# Почему в предложении стоит тире?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

*Она начинается ещё в протерозойскую эру – настолько древний и малоисследованный этап истории нашей планеты, что учёные даже не делят его на периоды и эпохи.*

В ответах к заданию ЕГЭ написано, что тире стоит перед приложением. Смущает наличие после тире сложноподчинённого предложения. Может ли быть приложение в составе СПП?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Приложение может быть в составе любого предложения - БСП,ССП,СПП. В данном примере придаточное предложение относится к **распространителю** приложения:

[*Она начинается ещё в протерозойскую эру – **настолько древний и малоисследованный** этап истории нашей планеты], (**что учёные даже не делят его на периоды и эпохи***).

Вполне корректная синтаксическая конструкция. Тире здесь действительно перед приложением, которое стоит в конце предложения, потому что в данном случае **придаточное тоже является по смыслу распространителем приложения**, как и другие выделительные конструкции - причастные обороты, пояснения и т.д.